# DynaTree Syntax Error in onLazyRead

Tags: javascript, django

I haven't touched Javascript in years.  So I am reacquainting myself with it and am basically a newbie again.

I am using Dynatree in a Django application.  I can load the first two levels of the tree with the initial call to Django.  However, when I add the onLazyRead function I get a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

The entire script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready((function(){
    // Initialize the tree in the onload event
    $("#prjtree").dynatree({
        title: "Projects",
        initAjax: {url: "/get_prjtree/",
               data: {key: "root", // Optional arguments to append to the url
                      mode: "all"
                      }
               },
            onLazyRead: function(node) {
            node.appendAjax({url: "/get_pcttree/",
                      data: {key: node.data.key, // Optional arguments to append to the url
                      mode: "all"
                      }
               });
        },

        onActivate: function(node) {
            alert("You activated " + node);
        },                

    });  // end DynaTree


}));
</script>
```

The error is on the line:

```
            node.appendAjax: {url: "/get_pcttree/",
```

I even tried rearranging the order of the functions.

If I comment out the entire onLazyRead function, it works as expected.

I just can't see where the problem is. I have compared it to several examples and it seems to be exactly like them.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe typo error in:
`node.appendAjax: {` , shouldnt it be `node.appendAjax({` ?

Comment: The reply from psulek was one part of the error.  There was at least one other (maybe two).  I updated to code with a working version. Thanks.